# ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc

Tags: java, jdbc

When I ran my web application under Eclipse IDE everything worked fine.
But when I exported my project into war-file and deployed in tomcat I've got following message:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc
```

I've tried putting sqljdbc4.jar everywhere:

- catalina-home\lib dir
- WEB-INF\lib dir
- both of them

What I'am missing?
Environment: tomcat 6.0.20, sql server 2005

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your driver class *name* is wrong. The exception text points to a package, not an actual driver class. And don't forget to restart Tomcat after changing the contents of various lib directories.

**Edit:** Your IDE might use different configuration than your deployed war. Or fail with the same exception silently but the driver itself was already loaded by other means - then the actual connection just works.

Comment: thnks for feedback
What you mean by saying "Your driver class is wrong" - that driver works fine under IDE

Comment: Regardless of what your IDE is doing, "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc" is not a driver class, it's a package.

Comment: I feel silly, but what conclusions I should draw from 
>>>"com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc" is not a driver class, it's a package

Comment: In general, if you see these kind of error messages, check your configuration for mistypes.

Answer (score 4):

The driver class is "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver". You've just missed the class name off the end.

Comment: I never remember the driver class names. These times I wish JDBC had automatic driver discovery.

Comment: skaffman,
I specified driver class in context.xml as following:
driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"

Comment: please post the relevent part of your context.xml file.

Comment: <Resource name="jdbc/db_name" type="javax.sql.DataSource" maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" url="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=db_name" driverClassName="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" username="sa" password="sa" />

Comment: For that configuration to work in the deployed version of your web application the JAR containing com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver has to be in $CATALINA_HOME/lib

Answer (score 0):

blah...
After reinstalling tomcat it worked just fine.
As kd304 said - maybe it was configuration issue
Thanks for your help